# how to import plugins from role on import_tasks

Tags: ansible

From playbook, i want to import specific task files from role

These tasks need role filter_plugin. When i use role, no problem but when i import tasks.

I have no filter named ...

My playbook

```yaml
- name: tasks to import
  hosts:
    - myhost
  tasks:
    - name: some tasts
      include_tasks: "../roles/tasks.yml"
```

and the error was

```
fatal: [myhosts]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'getservice'. String: {{ item.key | getservice }}.j2"}
```

> Fiter was in filter_plugins directory of role

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> Q *"Filter was in filter_plugins directory of the role."*

A: See how plugins are loaded [Adding a plugin locally](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-plugin-locally).

To solve the problem either put the path to `filter_plugins` into the configuration or link the `filter_plugins` directory into the current directory.